# Swift Error: Struct 'XX' must be completely initialized before a member is stored to

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, core-audio

I am trying to define AudioStreamBasicDescription in Swift.

In Objective-C, I used something like the following code.

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription ASBD;
ASBD.mSampleRate            = 8000;
ASBD.mFormatID              = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
ASBD.mFormatFlags           = kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical | kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
ASBD.mFramesPerPacket       = 1;
ASBD.mChannelsPerFrame      = 1;
ASBD.mBitsPerChannel        = 16;
ASBD.mBytesPerPacket        = 2;
ASBD.mBytesPerFrame         = 2;
```

And my converted Swift code is bellow

```
var ASBD: AudioStreamBasicDescription
ASBD.mSampleRate = 8000  // ERROR here
ASBD.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM
ASBD.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked
ASBD.mFramesPerPacket = 1
ASBD.mChannelsPerFrame = 1
ASBD.mBitsPerChannel = 16
ASBD.mBytesPerPacket = 2
ASBD.mBytesPerFrame = 2
```

But the second line of this swift code is throwing this error. I don't know why i am getting this error. Can anyone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This means that a structure needs to be completely initialized before using it. `AudioStreamBasicDescription` is a structure, so you need to initialize it before using it. The right code would be the following:

```
var ASBD: AudioStreamBasicDescription! = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
ASBD.mSampleRate = 8000
ASBD.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM
ASBD.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked
ASBD.mFramesPerPacket = 1
ASBD.mChannelsPerFrame = 1
ASBD.mBitsPerChannel = 16
ASBD.mBytesPerPacket = 2
ASBD.mBytesPerFrame = 2
```

Comment: Is the `!` necessary!